# Excel Transpose Remove Duplicate Entries

Tags: vba, excel

I have two spreadsheets. The first spreadsheet has a part number and description in the same column but consecutive rows. I need to take the part number and descriptions from the first spreadsheet and then transpose them (values only, no formatting) onto the second spreadsheet so that now part number and description are in consecutive columns instead of rows. To help with this I added the following VBA code to the Worksheet_Change() function.

```
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, MatNumDesc) Is Nothing Then

   If Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy Then

        Application.Undo
        Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

   End If

End If
```

MatNumDesc is a range of cells where I would paste in the part number. If I have 2+ material and descriptions everything works fine, my problem is when there is only one material and description. In those cases I get a duplicate entry that I do not want.

To be clear, I am manually copying and pasting values (using Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V) between the two spreadsheets which are separate files. I am not using any VBA code to try and copy from one sheet to another as for reasons not worth going into, it would not work with my setup.

Also, from what I've been able to observe, the actual issue I'm facing has to do with default Excel behavior. What I copy is 2 rows and 1 column of data. When transposed it becomes 2 columns and 1 row, however after the `.Application.Undo` operation runs, 2 rows and 2 columns are selected which Excel then runs the `.PasteSpecial` operation on. At least from what I have been able to observe.

Comment: On a whim I tried replacing `Target.PasteSpecial` with `.Range("G" & Target.Row).PasteSpecial` (along with the bits of code needed to make that work that I'm leaving out) and it seems to be working so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing I believe I have found at least a solution. Instead of using `Target` which is defined by Excel, an explicit range must be named. So the corrected version of the initial code would be like the following.

```
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, MatNumDesc) Is Nothing Then

    If Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy Then

        Application.Undo
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & Target.Row).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

    End If

End If
```

In this example column "G" is used, but it could be replaced with any other column.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little hard to debug with the limited section of code you've offered but a standard practice within a `Worksheet_Change` event macro that changes values is to temporarily turn off `.EnableEvents` in order that the sub's actions do not trigger another event where it tries to run on top of itself.

```
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, MatNumDesc) Is Nothing Then
   If Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy Then
        on error goto Fìn
        application.enableevents = false   ' turn off event handling
        Application.Undo
        Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
   End If
End If
Fìn:
application.enableevents = true  'remember to turn it back on before exiting the sub
```

Comment: I already have both `.EnableEvents` and `.ScreenUpdating` off. Excel does not crash or anything like would be typical if `.EnableEvents` hadn't been set to false, I just get a single unwanted duplicate value when I have a single part number and description pair.